# Glassfish 3.1.2 Faces Servlet xhtml not processing properly / missing output

Tags: jsf-2, facelets, glassfish-3

I have two similar pages, one named index.xhtml and one named index_old.xhtml both in the Web Pages root, as seen in NetBeans 7.1.2.

index.xhtml processes properly and has the correct output.

index_old.xhtml seems to show only the hard coded text and nothing else.

When index.xhtml --> index_older.xhtml & index_old.xhtml --> index.xhtml then the formerly not functioning properly index_old.xhtml now displays the correct output & the formerly correctly working index.xhtml now does not display the proper output.

Why is this happening?  How is this issue resolved?

The following are my index files:

index.xhtml:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' ?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html">
<h:head>
<title>Development Environment - THIS SITE IS A LIVE VIEW OF A WORK IN PROGRESS</title>
<h:outputStylesheet name="css/jsfcrud.css"/>
</h:head>
<h:body>
<h:graphicImage id="logo" value="/images/logo.PNG" width="256" height="55" />
<br />
<br />
Development Environment - THIS SITE IS A LIVE VIEW OF A WORK IN PROGRESS.
<br />
<br />
This is a live, fully functioning dynamic web site for the migration of the Service and Naming Standards Inventory workbook to
a web enabled, database hosted application.<br />  It's purpose is to allow for testing and development of expected functionality before
the application is deployed to a production server.<br />
<br />
For feature requests, change requests, and bug reports, please send a detailed email to 
<br />
<br />
<a href="/SNSI/secureNOC/indexSecure.xhtml">NOC personnel log in here</a>
<br />
<br />
<a href="/SNSI/secureBasic/indexBasic.xhtml">Other authorized personnel log in here</a>
</h:body>
</html>
```

index_old.xhtml:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' ?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html">
<h:head>
<title>Development Environment - THIS SITE IS A LIVE VIEW OF A WORK IN PROGRESS</title>
<h:outputStylesheet name="css/jsfcrud.css"/>
</h:head>
<h:body>
<h:graphicImage id="logo" value="/images/logo.PNG" width="256" height="55" />
<br />
<br />
Development Environment - THIS SITE IS A LIVE VIEW OF A WORK IN PROGRESS.
<br />
<br />
This is a live, fully functioning dynamic web site for the migration of the Service and Naming Standards Inventory workbook to
a web enabled, database hosted application.<br />  It's purpose is to allow for testing and development of expected functionality before
the application is deployed to a production server.<br />
<br />
For feature requests, change requests, and bug reports, please send a detailed email to 
<br />
<br />
<h:form>
<h:commandLink action="/darkFiber/List" value="Open Dark Fiber Table" target="_blank"/>
</h:form>
<h:form>
<h:commandLink action="/darkFiberCircuitIdAid/List" value="Open Dark Fiber Circuit ID Aid Table" target="_blank"/>
</h:form>
</h:body>
</html>
```

---

Changed as BalusC suggested and received an error and stack trace as a result.  Please see below for the error & stack trace:

```
An Error Occurred:
/faces/index.xhtml Not Found in ExternalContext as a Resource
- Stack Trace

com.sun.faces.context.FacesFileNotFoundException: /faces/index.xhtml Not Found in ExternalContext as a Resource
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.impl.DefaultFaceletFactory.resolveURL(DefaultFaceletFactory.java:232)
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.impl.DefaultFaceletFactory.resolveURL(DefaultFaceletFactory.java:273)
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.impl.DefaultFaceletFactory.getMetadataFacelet(DefaultFaceletFactory.java:209)
    at com.sun.faces.application.view.ViewMetadataImpl.createMetadataView(ViewMetadataImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.RestoreViewPhase.execute(RestoreViewPhase.java:233)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.RestoreViewPhase.doPhase(RestoreViewPhase.java:116)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.execute(LifecycleImpl.java:118)
    at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:593)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.service(StandardWrapper.java:1542)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:281)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:175)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.doInvoke(StandardPipeline.java:655)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.invoke(StandardPipeline.java:595)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:161)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.doService(CoyoteAdapter.java:331)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:231)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper$AdapterCallable.call(ContainerMapper.java:317)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:195)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.invokeAdapter(ProcessorTask.java:849)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.doProcess(ProcessorTask.java:746)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.process(ProcessorTask.java:1045)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.DefaultProtocolFilter.execute(DefaultProtocolFilter.java:228)
    at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.executeProtocolFilter(DefaultProtocolChain.java:137)
    at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:104)
    at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:90)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.HttpProtocolChain.execute(HttpProtocolChain.java:79)
    at com.sun.grizzly.ProtocolChainContextTask.doCall(ProtocolChainContextTask.java:54)
    at com.sun.grizzly.SelectionKeyContextTask.call(SelectionKeyContextTask.java:59)
    at com.sun.grizzly.ContextTask.run(ContextTask.java:71)
    at com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:532)
    at com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:513)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That can happen if you have mapped the `FacesServlet` in `web.xml` on an URL pattern of `/index.xhtml` instead of `*.xhtml`.

Fix it accordingly.

```
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>facesServlet</servlet-name> <!-- Or whatever name it has -->
    <url-pattern>*.xhtml</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

---

**Update**: as per your new problem after the change,

> com.sun.faces.context.FacesFileNotFoundException: /faces/index.xhtml Not Found in ExternalContext as a Resource

Remove the `/faces` part from the URL in browser address bar.

Comment: Thank you for the reply.  I changed web.xml source code as you suggested.  The page no longer loads.  I will post the  error & stack trace.

Comment: Just edit it in your question. You shouldn't post it as an answer, because, well, it isn't an answer.

Comment: Remove the `/faces` part from the URL in browser address bar.

Comment: Will do, thank you.  This is my first experience using stackoverflow.com.  I've got the hang of posting/reply/answer now.